# Database not created using Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Node.js and this is the first time I am using MongoDB.

Connection seems to work but database is never created.

I have created user model because I thought a record needs to be created so that it creates the database

I'm not sure what am I missing here.

**index.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

//DB setup
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/hotel", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

// CONNECTION EVENTS
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
  console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + 'mongodb://localhost:27017/hotel');
});

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});

// When the connection is disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
  console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
});

// If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection 
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  mongoose.connection.close(function() {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

**user.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Defined models
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    password: String
});

//Create model class
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

//Export the model
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

I have also tried adding .save() function but didn't seem to work

```
ModelClass.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

Comment: you are saying that `user model is created and adding that to database`. But if your database `hotel` is not created then in which database your user model is saved?

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: @AfridaAnzumAesha sorry maybe I didn't explained it right, but that was not what I thought. Please check my question update.

Comment: @mehta-rohan nope... :/

Comment: @user9347049 Can you please change the model name from user to users

Comment: can you go to you cli and check what all databases are there?

Comment: @PrinceDevadoss I don't think that is issue because mongoDB sets it to plural itself..

Comment: @mehta-rohan admin, config, local, test these are databases that are there

Comment: but you are not saving any data to database, then how it will create the database? your `ModelClass.save` should not work then

Comment: and where do you initialize ModelClass? You must have added email and password to this model.

Comment: @AfridaAnzumAesha well I thought I have saving it with `.save()` function. Check it it is in the end of my question

Comment: @mehta-rohan Why?

Comment: because to save some values in your DB you have to provide these value to your model and then save it.

Comment: @mehta-rohan ahaaa you mean like that okay, let me try and will let you know if works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to initialize the monogoose model with original value and then save it. i.e

```
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
var user = new ModelClass({ email: 'Rover@rover.in', password: 'dog' });
// Now user.save function
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution.